# LPV, WAAS/EGNOS and GLS in 737 NG

Tags: boeing-737, approach, rnav

As far as I understand, there are mainly 3 types of RNP approaches:

- **LNAV/VNAV** - we have a set of fixes with altitudes and flying it
- **LPV WAAS/EGNOS** - same as 1, but aircraft use special receiver equipment based on geostationary satellites, that's why it's so-called SBAS (sattelite-based)
- **LPV GLS** - which is same as ILS, uses GPS + signals from ground equipment. It's so-called GBAS (ground-based)

Let's take EPRZ RNP Rwy 09.
[image]
Here we can see three options:

1. **LPV CAT 1** - which I assume shall use EGNOS (V in LPV is vertical)
2. **LNAV/VNAV** - which I assume use only FIXes and altitudes
3. **LNAV CDFA** - which I assume uses LNAV and I need to descend somehow (V/S or glide path angle)

In terms of 737 NG, LNAV/VNAV and CDFA are straightforward.

1. Do I need to "tune" WAAS/EGNOS channel somehow? Referring to this [LPV/LP approach (RNAV with WAAS): What is actually the "channel number"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23823/lpv-lp-approach-rnav-with-waas-what-is-actually-the-channel-number) it seems like no
2. If I don't need to tune EGNOS channel, what is the difference between LNAV/VNAV and LPV WAAS/EGNOS regarding the procedures? How do I know, if aircraft is ready for LPV with EGNOS/WAAS?
3. Approach is called LPV **CAT 1**, on the other hand, in EPGD RNP approach named just **LPV**. What is the CAT 1 here?
4. Can IAN be used (if equipped) instead of LPV, LNAV/VNAV and LNAV CDFA?
5. I assume something here is related to ANP/RNP, but chart has no RNP minimum values listed here. What are the general rules, I probably missed?

FCOM 737 says only about ILS/GLS (normal procedure) and supplementary SP 4.7 Instrument Approach - RNAV (RNP) AR, but in such case it's non-AR approach.

*I'm not 737 pilot yet, using 737 in simulators only*

Comment: Regarding your 5th question: [What RNP level is required for an RNP approach if the chart does not specify a value?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/80898/what-rnp-level-is-required-for-an-rnp-approach-if-the-chart-does-not-specify-a-v)